# Where to look up for bing search api app id?

Tags: api, search, bing, app-id

I'm trying to use bing search api but not sure where to find the app id

http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=&Query=xbox%20site:microsoft.com&Sources=Image&Version=2.0&Market=en-us&Adult=Moderate&Image.Count=10&Image.Offset=0&JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=SearchCompleted

Answer (score 1):

You can get this from the Azure Data Marketplace where the Bing Search API is made available: http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search